# Как написать парсер медиафайлов (аудио/видео)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, аудио, видео

На StackOverFlow уже был подобный вопрос, но там человеку нужно было написать парсер **Фото**. Но фото на большинстве сайтов, уже расположены на странице. А аудио может открываться например только после нажатия кнопки "Play". Так как вытащить ссылку из этой кнопки или пройтись по унаследованным страницам, и проверить есть ли там эти кнопки, и вытащить уже из них?

Comment: давайте сайт, будем думать ;)

Comment: https://ruv.hotmo.org/ Вот для примера. На этой странице около 30 кнопок play (желательно чтобы парсер был универсален)

Comment: в элементах 'a', class='track__download-btn' есть ссылки на скачивание, можно не жать на Play

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Понял